# Bootstrap carousel items get stacked on top of each other when window is re-sized

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am developing a carousel with Bootstrap which also needs to be responsive. It works pretty well when the `screen width` is bigger than `1200px`, but when it's lower the elements get stacked one above each other.

This is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/at449HghkG) with the code. What I would like to get is that the `items` are displayed on the same line and eventually if one of them overflows, it has to go on a new line.

Does some of you have a suggestion of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: You cannot post a question with a link to a sandbox editor (either JSFiddle, Bootply, Codepen, etc) without **also** including all relevant code in your question. This warning usually appears when using JSFiddle, but may not have as Bootply isn't as well known. Please edit all relevant code into your question.

Comment: [This](http://www.bootply.com/89193) should help you solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your element has col-lg-2 class which has float:left for media > 1200px. anything less than that does not float left. Add other classes for different devices such as col-xs-2, col-sm-2, col-md-2

Comment: Apparently your suggestion was right, I changed the class to `col-xs-2` and it worked. Thanks!